# Is it possible that onPause() gets called if onResume() hasn't been called before?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, illegalargumentexception, activity-lifecycle, receiver

I register receiver in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()` method. I can strange error in my Crashlytics reports:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to pause activity {package-here}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: 

Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Receiver not registered:
```

It happened 3 times (3 users) on 20k installs.

**Is it possible that onPause() gets called if onResume() hasn't been called before?** I thought it isn't.

Answer (score 5):

If it is Samsung device then yes, it is possible: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37001269#c3

Comment: Yes, it happened only on Samsung devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you open and close the app too often(Multiple times in 1 second),it will happen